# Why does autowiring not work in the following:

Tags: spring

I have the follosing classes:

```
@component
public class Car extends abstract Vehicle {

  public Car() {
    super(10);
  }

}


public abstract class Vehicle {

   @Autowired
   private Validator em;

   public Vehicle(int i) {
     // init
   }

  public int getVehicle() {
  }
}
```

when i create the bean using the following:

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(..)
```

it failes with an exception stating cannot inject validator bean...

However if i change the autowiring to setter injection it works as follows:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {


   private Validator em;

   public Vehicle(int i) {
     // init
   }

   public int getVehicle() {
   }

   @Autowired
   public set Em(Validator em) {
     this.em = em;
   }
```

}

Can somebody explain this to me, is is something to do with the way the bena lifecycle works?

Comment: `public class Car extends abstract Vehicle` This syntax is incorrect. Get rid of the `abstract`.

Comment: You must be doing something weird in `Validator` or elsewhere because I just tried with the code you posted and an empty `Validator` class and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows `@Autowiring` in abstract class so I don't see any problems here. As this works if you put annotation on setter I suspect that you have some kind of cycling dependencies with `Validator` class so that is why you have to put annotation on setter.

Comment: Nope i have no cyclic dependency.. as the valdiator is a basic class with no autowiring..just a component... im a little lost as to why.. all i could think of was that maybe the bean lifecycle is casuing something... stepping through the code.. i can see that when the constructor is called the validator is null...

Comment: And this is only place where it is injected?

Comment: Very strange. Can you please post stack trace?